# Adding RTMP plugin (gstreamer-plugin-bad-0.10.23) support to Gstreamer Android SDK 2013.6 Congo

Tags: android, gstreamer, rtmp

I'm currently trying to configure RTMP plugin with the GSTREAMER Android SDK release 2013.6 version. I was able to cross compile the RTMP plugin for and was successful in creating the libgstrtmp.a and the libgstrtmp.la files.

Then I added this files to the gstreamer-0.10 folder in the GSTREAMER Android SDK's libs folder. I then took the sample tutorial-5 from the SDK base and made the changes in the Android.mk file and then recompile the project.

After all this the RTMP plugin was statically registered in the libgstreamer_android.so but when i run the application providing a rtmp stream I get the following error's

> g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
>
> g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

and the following warnings.

> specified instance size for type `GstRTMPSrc' is smaller than the parent type's`GstPushSrc' instance size
>
> specified instance size for type `GstRTMPSink' is smaller than the parent type's`GstBaseSink' instance size

Can someone help me troubleshoot this error. As per the Gstreamer SDK FAQ's this mismatch between the instances and the parent class might be due to compilation with two different versions of gstreamer. That is my plugin is compiled with some other version than that of the SDK.

My Another question is that against what version of the gstreamer version is the Android SDK compiled. As this might be the main culprit in the error.

Thanking You.

Dhruv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the 1.x versions of GStreamer, the currently latest stable release can be found here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.2.4.1/
This release also contains the RTMP plugin.

Also the 0.10 versions are no longer supported by the community since a few years, and you're missing literally thousands of bugfixes, new features and other improvements.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Dröge,that was really helpful. But I'm again stuck up at one more problem while playing the RTMP stream in Tutorial 5 for Gstreamer-1.0. It plays the default media link without any issues, but when I change the default media URI and the pipeline with my own RTMP stream(live) the buffer would be stuck after buffering a video,random for 1 or 7 sec. The video would be stuck at the first frame that it has captured. It doesn't render and the state would remain PAUSED. Sometimes on random the player crashes with an error INVALID heap and SIGSEGV. Please suggest the probable cause.

Comment: Does it work better with GStreamer on Linux? In any case, can you file a bug about those crashes at http://bugzilla.gnome.org against GStreamer? It should never crash, that's a bug.

Comment: I solved the problem of the buffer crash and invalid heap storage by integrating some chunks from the Linux's playback-tutorial-4 to Android Media player tutorial 5. The results were quite good, but the only thing that I screwed up with was the seek bar that was disable somehow during the migration. Otherwise, it's a complete working RTMP media player. Thanks especially to you for migrating me from 0.10 to 1.2.4 version. And about the bug I think you need to update the refresh_ui function as per in playback-tutorial-4. It was a great reference. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Can you possibly tell me a perfect reason why the RTMP stream lags as well as gets stuck at some moments and then plays random frame that it is able to decode and neglecting the remaining frame. Whats going wrong here with the  streamer. I'm streaming a local in-house video and the local LAN connection speed is supported to somewhere around 12 MBPS. Still the frames appeared to be in a delayed motion. Is this because of the time stamping issue.? The video is streamed in h.264. This is the issue only with the live stream.? Can you suggest me probable cause for this?

Comment: There's probably a bug in the rtmp plugin. Best would be to file a bug report at http://bugzilla.gnome.org against GStreamer and also provide a sample stream that shows the described behaviour.